# Implicit narrowing when summing constants vs explicit narrowing when summing variables

Tags: java, int, byte, addition, primitive-types

I have written a program.

```
class First
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                int c = 5;
                byte b = c+6;
                System.out.println(b);
        }
}
```

And my javac output is:

```
error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
        byte b = c+6;
                  ^
1 error
```

But if I modify the program as:

```
class First
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                byte b = 5+6;
                System.out.println(b);
        }
}
```

It executes fine, output:

```
11
```

I know that before operation, both operands gets converted in integer. Then the + operator results in an integer. But if the variable c was an integer, then the constant 5 is also an integer by default. Why does not javac results an error in the second case?

Please guide me if I am conceptually wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Section 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) of the JLS :

> The compile-time narrowing of constant expressions means that code such as:
>
> byte theAnswer = 42;
>   is allowed. Without the narrowing, the fact that the integer literal 42 has type int would mean that a cast to byte would be required:
>
> byte theAnswer = (byte)42;  // cast is permitted but not required

A constant expression is further defined in [Section 15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) of the JLS.

Since the expression `5+6` is a constant expression that fits within the range of `byte`, it will automatically  be narrowed at compile time without the need of an explicit cast. On the other hand, since the expression `c+6` is not a constant expression, it will not be automatically narrowed and an explicit cast is required.